# Angular 2 emit when Http has finished to subsequently run another function

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a general function to doing a DELETE call to my API. The function is something like this:

```
deleteItem(url, item, action) {
    return this.http.delete(url)
        .subscribe(
            () => this.store.dispatch({ type: action, payload: item }),
            error => this.errorHandler(error),
            () => console.debug('Delete complete')
        )
    ;
```

I call this function from a few places sending in different urls, items and actions. Let's say I've got a function like this:

```
deleteBookcase(bookcase) {
    this.apiService.deleteItem(BOOKCASE_URL, bookcase, BOOKCASE_REMOVE);
}
```

Sometimes, I'd like to trigger another action once an item has been deleted from the API. For example, maybe I want to check whether my global store of books has changed now I removed bookcase.

Is there a simple way to let my `deleteBookcase` functions know that the HTTP call and subsequent actions have completed before prematurely triggering an extra action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `map()` instead of `subscribe()` in `deleteItem()`

```
deleteItem(url, item, action) {
    return this.http.delete(url)
        .map(() => this.store.dispatch({ type: action, payload: item })
        .catch((error) => this.errorHandler(error))
        .do(() => console.debug('Delete complete'))
 });
}
```

and subscribe where you call `deleteItem()`

```
deleteBookcase(bookcase) {
    this.apiService.deleteItem(BOOKCASE_URL, bookcase, BOOKCASE_REMOVE)
    .subscribe(data => doSomething());
}
```

Don't forget to import `do`, `map`, `catch`

Comment: Why trigger the store dispatch using `map()` rather than `do()`?

Comment: I didn't look to close at what the code is doing. If the result should be forwarded to the subscriber, you need `map()`, if you only want to invoke a call then and don't care about the result or handle the result inside the `do` or `map` callback, then `do` is the better fit. If the call returns an observable then `flatMap()` might be an even better fit.

Answer (score 3):

To do this, I would refactor your methods this way:

```
deleteItem(url, item, action) {
  return this.http.delete(url)
      .catch((error) => {
        // handle error
      })
      .do(() => {
        this.store.dispatch({ type: action, payload: item });
      });
}

deleteBookcase(bookcase) {
    this.apiService.deleteItem(BOOKCASE_URL, bookcase, BOOKCASE_REMOVE).subscribe(() => {
      // do something
    });
}
```

Use the `do` operator if the action is executed outside the asynchronous data flow. If you want to notify after the call to `dispatch` ends (and return an observable), you could use the `flatMap` one:

```
deleteItem(url, item, action) {
  return this.http.delete(url)
      .catch((error) => {
        // handle error
      })
      .flatMap(() => {
        return this.store.dispatch({ type: action, payload: item });
      });
}
```

By refactoring your method this way, you need to be careful since observables are lazy so calling `deleteItem` without subscribing won't execute the request:

```
// Request isn't executed
this.deleteItem();

// Request is executed
this.deleteItem().subscribe(() => {
});
```

Comment: So if I've used `this.apiService.deleteItem().subscribe(() => something())` within my `deleteBookcase` function, does that subscription get destroyed once `deleteBookcase` has finished executing?

Comment: In fact yes since HTTP observables are one shot. I mean only one event is triggered: the response.